# error uknown fuction "msg": al usar Toastr1.Msg(ToastrType.Warning, "Mi mensaje de advertencia", "Título") Genexus Ev3

Tags: genexus, genexusxev3

Buen día:

Estoy prograando en Genexus Evolution 3 y me está generando el error siguiente al momento de utilizar mensajes:

**error uknown fuction "msg"**

Esto al usar  **Toastr1.Msg(ToastrType.Warning, "Mi mensaje de advertencia", "Título")**

Alguien que me apoye.
http://marketplace.genexus.com/product.aspx?toastr,en

Saludos cordiales.